# The new url id is getting appended after the previous request's url

Tags: python, html, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I'm making a get request in django using html form as:

crud.html

```
<form action="{% url 'crudId' id %}" method="get">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group" style="width: 20%;margin-top: 5px">
                        <label for="name">Id</label>
                        <input type="number" name="id" value="{% if data %}{{ id }}{% endif %}">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="OK" style="width: 30%; margin-left: 40%">
                    ...
```

my view for this:

```
class CrudPageView(View):

    def get(self, request, id=1):
        # get the id from the page
        oid = id
        ...
        # some data and operation
        ...
        return render(request, 'crud.html', {'data': data, 'id': oid})
```

and in urls.py as :

```
 path('crud/', CrudPageView.as_view(), name='crud'),
 path('crud/id=<int:id>', CrudPageView.as_view(), name='crudId')
 ...
```

so http://localhost:8000/crud/ does work as intended and shows the page with data of id = 1;
when I input any id, it also works as intended and shows the data for that id, but the url is in the form `http://localhost:8000/crud/id=1?id=5` and after another input it will be `http://localhost:8000/crud/id=5?id=12`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, you basically made `GET` request twice. when accessing the `crud/` and after submitting the form?

Comment: Did I? I'm a little confused here.

Comment: I think you did. Try to separate the method for rendering the `crud.html` and submitting the form. So, in the URL you'll have two different views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def index(request, id) -> HttpResponse:
    # some data

    return render(request, 'websites/index.html', context={'data': data, 'id': id})


def get(request) -> HttpResponse:
    id_number = request.GET.get('number')
    # some data

    return redirect(index, id=id)
```

Comment: That's what I had to do, make two views; one for form get method to redirect and another for rendering, Thanks.